# Swift. Вывод строки

Tags: swift

Есть ли критическая разница в этих двух вариантах записи вывода? Конкретно интересует запись в скобках:

```
print("Hello", name, "world")

print("Hello \(name) world")
```

Результат получается одинаковый, отсюда и возник вопрос.

Comment: Во втором случае форматируется строка, в первом выводится список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функциональной **разницы нет** вообще **никакой**, единственное - запятая делает пробел **ДО** запятой или **ПОСЛЕ** `строки`.

А так - можете смело использовать **первый** `print("hello \(wolrd)")` или **второй** вариант `print("Hello",name,"world")`.